# Find coordinates of point on map

Tags: coordinate-system, georeferencing

I have scanned map I know it scale and dpi. Is it possible if i know `lon-lat` cords of some `point(X,Y)` calculate `lon-lat` of another point (clicked) on this map? I have read some about georeferencing tools but I'm looking for programming functions to achieve such result.

Comment: What do you mean by programming functions?

Comment: I'mean simply i give `X-Y` mouse position over map and i recive `lat-lon`coordinates

Answer (score 3):

Due to the warping of the paper on which the map is printed and the scan procedure itself a scanned map will always contain distortions to some extent. That's why methods like georeferencing  have been developed and should be applied in order to add a spatial reference to the map.

Of course you could try to map the pixel coordinates to a location on the scanned map based on the known parameters. But without transforming the map you are very likely to compute coordinates that are far away from the reality. However there are libraries like for example "GeoTools" which provide methods that could help you when looking for a programmatical solution.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I have little additional question, how can i detect what projection has been used? On my map i dont have any lines just streets and buildings, i know only the scale, it is some kind of administrative map

Comment: If you have an original map document there could/should be some information given somewhere. Otherwise you could maybe try to find out which projection is usually used for other administrative maps of the desired region.